# How to setup 1.1 version of django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I wanna read a book in django caled "Practical Django projects second edition", but it is outdated as the version of django used in the book was 1.1. I really wanna read this book because it really fits my needs as i working on a project with the same theme, but i have no idea how to run the examples or use django 1.1.
Any suggestions?

Comment: You can install Django with `pip install django==1.1.4`, but it's a really bad idea. Django 1.1 is years out of date and insecure. If you're learning Django in 2017 then please choose a book that is written for at least Django 1.8.

Comment: @Alasdair Thank you for your suggestion. but the situation is i am so new in web development and i have to complete an educational website that has a blog, cms and a code sharing application. i did not find an updated book that explains how to make such things specially the code sharing app, that's why i need this book even if it is out dated.

Comment: Just search "theboston django", that is the best play-list for a beginner, even i learned from those tutorials. Highly recommend use **latest Django version**

Comment: Here the link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qgGIqRFvFFk&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK

Answer (score 0):

you can install any version of Django, just use below practice to do that.
Create virtual environment for it, and install any version you want like.

```
pip install django==x.y.z
```

or using easy_install

```
easy_install django==x.y.z
```

if you are new with Django, then I will recommend you to try newest/current version.